# Where/what to check in Openshot to see why GPU render doesn't work?

Tags: video-editor, encoding, nvidia

I've been using OpenShot for a while on Fedora Linux from 27-33 and mostly not much problems.  I did notice occasionally that Render via GPU didn't work, but then I restarted the App, and was compiling again.
I have laptop with NV GTX 1500 TI with RPFusion nvidia drivers on, and since an update and install of cuda.  Openshot stopped working.  It gives me a message

```
Sorry, there was an error exporting your video: error while writing raw video frame
```

If I try to use ffmpeg with h.264 or h.265 directly it does encode normally.  So I'm not sure where to even look for detailed error info and howto go about solving this problem.

Comment: This seems very likely to be a bug or incompatibility of Openshot to the newest version of the driver/or CUDA and should be reported to the people who maintain this software. I doubt we can help you here.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I was thinking if there was some debugging option or any other way to get more specific error.